# How can mongomock can be use with motor?

Tags: python, pymongo, python-mock

I have a server implemented with Tornado, and Motor, 
and I've come across this mock of pymongo:
https://github.com/vmalloc/mongomock

I really like the idea of doing the unit tests of my code with no real call to the DB, for the sake of running them very fast.

I've tried patching motor to pass calls to the mongomock, like that:

```
from mock import MagicMock
import mongomock
p = mock.patch('motor.MotorClient.__delegate_class__', new=mongomock.MongoClient)
p1 = mock.patch('motor.MotorDatabase.__delegate_class__', new=MagicMock())

p.start()
p1.start()

def fin():
    p.stop()
    p1.stop()

request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

it was failing like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\venv\lib\site-packages\pytest_tornado\plugin.py", line 136, in http_server
    http_app = request.getfuncargvalue(request.config.option.app_fixture)
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1337, in getfuncargvalue
    return self._get_active_fixturedef(argname).cached_result[0]
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1351, in _get_active_fixturedef
    result = self._getfuncargvalue(fixturedef)
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1403, in _getfuncargvalue
    val = fixturedef.execute(request=subrequest)
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1858, in execute
    self.yieldctx)
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1784, in call_fixture_func
    res = fixturefunc(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\PycharmProjects\pyrecman\tests\__init__.py", line 65, in app
    return get_app(db=motor_db(io_loop))
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\PycharmProjects\pyrecman\tests\__init__.py", line 27, in motor_db
    return motor.MotorClient(options.mongo_url, io_loop=io_loop)[options.db_name]
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\venv\lib\site-packages\motor\__init__.py", line 1003, in __getattr__
    return MotorDatabase(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\venv\lib\site-packages\motor\__init__.py", line 1254, in __init__
    delegate = Database(connection.delegate, name)
  File "C:\Users\ifruchte\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 61, in __init__
    **connection.write_concern)
TypeError: attribute of type 'Collection' is not callable
```

Anyone know how it can be done ? or I'm wasting my time here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to instantiate the magicmock.

`p1 = mock.patch('motor.MotorDatabase.__delegate_class__', new=MagicMock)`

Comment: This does not work. Could you please provide a working scenario?